# vb6 installed on virtual machine cannot see the files stored in the same virtual machine

Tags: vb6, vmware

I installed VB6 on my virtual machine. My vmware virsion is 5.0.1 build-894247.

I tried to use VB6 to read some data under C:\ . However, it is not able to find that file. Then I did a trial that used VB6 to capture the files under the C drive. I have the following files:

- AUTOEXEC.BAT
- caldbinstall.txt
- CONFIG.SYS

The code I used to capture the files under the C drive:

```
Dim file As String

file = Dir("C:\")

Do While Len(file)
    Debug.Print file
    file = Dir()
Loop
```

Comment: Please post your code that reads data, and then the code to "capture the files under c drive", whatever that means.

Comment: thx for ur reply, I added in my question

Comment: If the file(s) you're looking for with this code have the hidden attribute set, then the default Dir function will not return those.  You'll need to add the vbHidden optional attribute to the command: Dir("C:\", vbHidden).  See [vb6 Dir syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262726(v=vs.60).aspx).  Or change the attribute on the file itself to not be hidden.